# How to unit test an node js express application

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, express

I want to begin doing unit testing on my node express project. what would be the simplest and easiest way to do this ?

Comment: Look into Mocha. It's a JavaScript testing framework that is oftentimes used with Node.js.  Once you play around with it, come back and edit this post so it's about a more specific problem.  Good luck!

Comment: Might be a good starting point: http://javascript.tutorialhorizon.com/2014/09/14/unit-test-your-nodejs-restful-api-using-mocha/ & https://thewayofcode.wordpress.com/2013/04/21/how-to-build-and-test-rest-api-with-nodejs-express-mocha/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are a following links.

1. **[Mocha](http://mochajs.org/)**

   Mocha is a feature-rich JavaScript test framework running on Node.js
   and the browser, making asynchronous testing simple and fun. Mocha
   tests run serially, allowing for flexible and accurate reporting,
   while mapping uncaught exceptions to the correct test cases.
2. **[Karma](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.13/index.html)**

   The main goal for Karma is to bring a productive testing environment
   to developers. The environment being one where they don't have to
   set up loads of configurations, but rather a place where developers
   can just write the code and get instant feedback from their tests.
3. **[Chai](http://chaijs.com/)**

   Chai is a BDD / TDD assertion library for node and the browser that
   can be delightfully paired with any javascript testing framework.
4. **[Jasmine](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine)**

   Jasmine is a Behavior Driven Development testing framework for
   JavaScript. It does not rely on browsers, DOM, or any JavaScript
   framework. Thus it's suited for websites, Node.js projects, or
   anywhere that JavaScript can run.
5. **[Blanket](http://blanketjs.org/)**

   Blanket.js is an easy to install, easy to configure, and easy to use
   JavaScript code coverage library that works both in-browser and with
   nodejs.

You may also follow the following tutorials

1. [Getting started with Mocha and Chai](http://robdodson.me/testing-backbone-boilerplate-with-mocha-and-chai/)
2. [Introduction to Jasmine JS](http://jasmine.github.io/2.1/introduction.html)
3. [Setting up a project using karma with mocha and chai](http://attackofzach.com/setting-up-a-project-using-karma-with-mocha-and-chai/)
4. [Node.js Testing Strategies](http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/nodejs-testing-strategies)
5. [Unit Testing with Node.js](http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/unit-testing-nodejs)

Answer (score 1):

[Mocha](http://mochajs.org) is a pretty solid solution for Node/Express. Their website has a [getting started](http://mochajs.org/#getting-started) page. A simple example:

```
var assert = require("assert");
var request = require('supertest');
var express = require('express');

// Module under test
var version = require('version');

describe('server.routes.version', function() {

    var app;

    beforeEach(function(done) {
        app = express();
        app.use('/version', version);
        done();
    });

    it('gets the product version', function (done) {

        var expected = {
            'version': '1.2.3'
        }

        request(app)
            .get('/version')
            .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
            .expect(200, expected)
            .end(function(err, res) {
                if (err) throw err;
                done();
            });
    });

});
```

If you need to mock out a Node module dependency (and eventually you probably will) things get a little more fiddly; I've had some success with a combination of [sandboxed-module](https://github.com/felixge/node-sandboxed-module) and [sinon](http://sinonjs.org):

```
var assert = require("assert");
var sinon = require('sinon');
var request = require('supertest');
var express = require('express');

describe('server.routes.version', function() {

    var app, version, mockConfig;

    beforeEach(function(done) {
        var mockConfig = sinon.mock({
            getVersion: function() {}
        });

        // Load the tested module within a sandbox
        var sandbox = require('sandboxed-module');
        version = sandbox.require('../server/routes/version', {
            requires: {
                '../config': mockConfig
            }
        });

        app = express();
        app.use('/version', version);
        done();
    });

    it('gets the product version', function (done) {

        mockConfig.expects('getVersion').once().returns('1.2.3');

        var expected = {
            'version': '1.2.3'
        }

        request(app)
            .get('/version')
            .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
            .expect(200, expected)
            .end(function(err, res) {
                mockConfig.verify();
                if (err) throw err;
                done();
            });
    });

});
```